# BASH - simple if statements dont work

Tags: bash, shell

Script look like this:

```
echo -e ""
read text

if [[ $text > 0 && $text < 3 ]]; then
        if[ $text == "0" ];
    then
        echo "Number is 0"
    fi
else
    echo "Number is odd"
fi
echo "You entered: $text"
```

I have error:

> ./build.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
>   ./build.sh: line 11:`  then'

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong I want make simple If in other If statement

Comment: You have forgotten a space here `if[ $text == "0" ];`

Comment: Besides the correct `if[` to `if [` - since this is *bash*, I think you want to be comparing `text` as an integer value and not a string. I'm thinking you want something closer to `if [ $text -gt 0 ] && [ $text -lt 3 ]; then` `-lt` and `-gt` will work on things as integers.

Comment: FYI, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points out these problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
if[ $text == "0" ];
```

With

```
if [ $text == "0" ];
```

As `bash` sees it, the former statement is an attempt to execute the command `if[` with arguments `$text`, `==`, `"0"`, and `]`.  Since `if[` is not `if`, it does not recognize that line as the start of an `if` statement.  Hence, the `then` which follows is "unexpected."

#### Aside on the `test` command

By the way, you are using both the older `[` and the more modern `[[` forms of the `test` command.  If you are new to `bash`, you may want to stick to the `[[` syntax because it offers fewer surprises.  The only advantage of the older `[` form is that it offers compatibility with other shells, particularly `dash` which is the default `/bin/sh` on debian-like systems.

There are some surprises, though, with both forms.  For one, `<` and `>` are not numeric comparison.  Instead, both, as `man bash` explains, "sort lexicographically using the current locale."  Thus, under my locale for example, the following statement returns true

```
[[ -1 > 0 ]]
```

If you want to do a numeric comparison, use the operator `-gt` for greater than.  Thus, the following returns false:

```
[[ -1 -gt 0 ]]
```

The other numeric comparison operators are `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, and `-ge`.

For more discussion of `[` and `[[`, see [Greg's BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

Comment: @AvinashRaj OK.  I added some discussion and a link to start to address that topic.